# Export a CSV file from MySQL to a local machine (OS X)

Tags: mysql, macos, csv, ssh, portforwarding

I'm trying to export a table from a database remotely using port binding and SSH.

So I'm logging in to the machine using:

```
ssh -L 3307:127.0.0.1:3306 user@IP
```

I then want to log in to MySQL and output the table in CSV format to my machines desktop.

Ideally I want this to be done all in one line but not getting much luck so far.. this is what I thought would work but it doesn't..

```
mysql -u root -p -e "USE dfs_va2; SELECT * FROM dfs_va2.artikel_trigger INTO OUTFILE '~/Desktop/my_output.csv’;”
```

Any help would be great!

Answer (score 0):

An option without port forwarding:

```
local-machine:~$ ssh user@IP \
                 "mysql -u mysql_user -p -N \
                 -e 'USE dfs_va2; SELECT * FROM dfs_va2.artikel_trigger;'" \
                 > ~/Desktop/my_output.tsv
```